# How to migrate the code using Six Module that will be compatible in python2 and python3 version

Tags: python

I want to provide six for compatible my code in python2 and python3 version. I have got the example from online but did not get more sources to get the six example in online. In the below code, i could not understand why they have created class for test cases and have written  this line

`class SampleTests(unittest.TestCase):`

and inside main, how did they call the class `SampleTests`?
and how `unittest.main()` inside main call the class?

Kindly help me. if possible kindly give some sample example of six module migration.

```
import six
from six.moves import reduce
import unittest


def multiply_values(val1, val2):
    return val1*val2

def add_values(val1, val2):
    return val1+val2

class SampleTests(unittest.TestCase):    
    def test_sets_equal(self):
        setValue1 = reduce(multiply_values, [1,2])
        setValue2 = reduce(add_values, [1,2])
        six.assertCountEqual(self, [2,3], [setValue1,setValue2])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `six` is used for two things:

- `reduce` was removed in Python 3 and replace by `functools.reduce` so `six` offers a handy "alias" for it so you can call `reduce` in both 2 and 3.
- `assertCountEqual` is part of unittest in Python 3 so `six` here provides its own implementation for Python 2.

The best documentation for the `six` module is available here: https://six.readthedocs.io/

Note: Python 2 is deprecated now and you shouldn't be using it for new projects. `six` will help you write code that works on both versions of Python but if you don't have a good reason for supporting Python 2, it would be better to write a Python 3 only code. [2to3 tool](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/2to3.html) can you help with converting Python 2 code to Python 3.

> why they have created class for test cases and have written this line class SampleTests(unittest.TestCase): and Inside main, how did they call the class SampleTests

This isn't really `six` specific question, this is how the `unittest` module works on both Python 2 and 3, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html for details.

TL;DR version: `unittest.main()` will automatically run all the test cases in the file and test case is defined as a function which name starts with `test_` in a `unittest.TestCase` class.

Comment: The documents are really helpful. Thanks for sharing. can anyone share some example that shows migration in six module along with the test cases? It will be more helpful.